# What is the Difference Between Assigning Method to JS Object Prototype vs to JS Object

Tags: javascript, oop

## Background

Working with OOP-style in JavaScript, by creating pseudo-classes using objects. From examples and walkthroughs online, I'd been under the impression that we need to set up an object, then attach function to that object's prototype object.

However, I have been playing around today and tried attaching a function directly to the object itself. From testing, I can't find any behavioral differences. Simplified example of both ways below:

#### Version 1

```
var Class = function( params ) {
}

Class.prototype.getData = function() {
    return _data;
};
```

#### Version 2

```
var Class = function( params ) {
    this.getData = function() {
        return _data;
    }
}
```

## Question

What is the difference, if any, between these two implementations?

Comment: difference is in defining method on `Class` instance or on `Class` instance prototype )